# Can I replace Office 365 with Office 2019?

Tags: microsoft-office-2019

Can I replace my existing Office 365 with Office 2019 on my computer using Windows 10? If so, how do I do it?

Comment: What exactly are you concerned would happen if you tried?

Comment: A cursory search reveals [this detailed help article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/how-do-i-upgrade-office-ee68f6cf-422f-464a-82ec-385f65391350?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).

Comment: Office 365 has all features that Office 2019.  Why do you want to replace your office install with a version with less features?

Comment: Personally, I just ended up with 365 by accident due to a uni license, and I found various features invasive and annoying to my workflow - it feels easier to revert to 2019 than to spend time configuring a version I like working with less.

Answer (score 2):

You may certainly switch from Office 365 to Office 2019.

You will need to uninstall Office 365 from *Control Panel > Programs and Features*,
then install Office 2019.

However, don't expect your Office 365 serial key to work for activating Office 2019.
A separate serial key must be bought for Office 2019.